# Hide phymyadmin per-row Edit/Copy/Delete actions

Tags: phpmyadmin

When browsing a table with many columns, I would like to maximize the width available for showing column data.

**Every row** has Links (icon & text) to perform Edit/Copy/Delete actions on a row.

**How do I hide those links?**

(If I want to perform the action, I'll use **row checkboxes** to select one or more rows, then perform action via corresponding "With selected" links below the rows.)

---

Existing SO questions that are NOT the same as this one:

[Hide phpmyadmin edit, copy and insert options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20409472/199364)
  (How to hide just *some* of the options.)

[How to show up 'edit','copy' and 'delete' buttons in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47903347/199364)
  (MULTIPLE similar questions - Asking why the options aren't showing up on a given table or query - this is a DYNAMIC display issue based on presence of unique ID - I'm asking for GLOBAL control of display LAYOUT.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are TWO "Settings" that affect these per-row action links.

These Settings are accessible via the **"Gear" icon (tooltip "Page-related settings") in upper-right** of browser page.

Near bottom of settings list, **"Where to show the table row links"** can **suppress these links completely ("Nowhere")** or move them "out of the way" ("Right").

An alternative is to make these (and similar actions) **take less room**, by changing **"How to display various action links"** from "Both" to **"Icons"**.

Answer (score 0):

*Found no viable solution on the internet, so had to dig down to the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/index.html) of phpMyAdmin. Found a solution, so I'm here to share it :)*

---

### Solution

All configurable data is placed in `config.inc.php` in phpMyAdmin’s top-level directory.
Navigate to this file.

Then, add this line to the end of the file:

```
$cfg['RowActionLinks'] = 'NONE';
```

Refresh phpMyAdmin. **Done!**

---

#### Documentation [[link]](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_RowActionLinks)

```
$cfg['RowActionLinks']
```

- `Type:`           `string`
- `Default value:`  `'left'`

  Defines the place where table row links (Edit, Copy, Delete) would be put when tables contents are displayed (you may have them displayed at the left side, right side, both sides or nowhere).

---